# "tibble 1.1 is not available" error for r notebook

Tags: r, rnotebook

Recently I occasionally encounter this error "tibble 1.1 is not available" yet I couldn't install it. any advice?

```
install.packages("tibble")

   package 'tibble' is available as a source package but not as a binary

Warning in install.packages :
  package 'tibble' is not available (as a binary package for R version 3.1.3)
```

Comment: upgrade your R version or try changing your cran mirror

Comment: or try to download the binary manually and run     install.packages("package", repos=NULL, type = "source")

Comment: @AlexNevsky Probably bad advice in this context, given that there is probably a good reason for the version dependency. Better idea might be to compile from source. In case OP is running Windows, this will require installation of the `devtools` package.

Comment: I tried to upgrade R from 3.1.3 to latest 3.3.1, however, couldn't open the installation pack, it stuck at 'verifying "R-3.3.1.pkg" '

Comment: thanks @AlexNevsky downloading from source worked!